# Root access with java.io.file on Android

Tags: java, android, file, root

I am trying to create a root file browser, however, I have some problems accessing root directories. When I try to access /data, the folder is empty.

When I do this:

```
File file = new File("/data/");
```

And then request for the items in that directory, it's empty. (No root access). I know how to execute simple root commands by using a `Process`, but then it won't work on phones without root.
So I need something that will work on all phones.

I thought about using `File` for unrooted devices and the command `ls` for rooted devices, but don't know if that's the best solution. I could also just use `ls` with or without root, but I'd like to use `File`.

Is there a way to make a root file browser, while also keeping support for non-rooted phones?

Thanks

Comment: You should check https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools and https://github.com/Stericson/RootShell

Comment: I tried with `File.listRoots()` method and listed the files success. and at some time it shows me the system folders when i used `file.getParent()` method.

Comment: @Guillaume Isn't that for rooted devices only? I want it to work on all devices. Also I prefer not to use external libraries.

Comment: @ELITE But will it show the files in root directories, and if it is a rooted device, will it be able to edit the files?

Comment: In my case it was showing files in System directories. I'm not sure if it allows you to edit files if device is rooted.

Comment: @ELITE `/system` is viewable on non rooted devices, you just can't edit the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggestion is correct. You cannot really use `File` on rooted devices for accessing the folders unavailable without root, so you'll definitely have to rely on `ls` in that case. Basically you have a choice between using `ls` everywhere and using an abstraction which will hide the details. In the latter case you will have a `File`-like interface which will use either `File`, or `ls` underneath.

I remember working on the same problem when I was designing my own file browser, and I opted for the second solution. It is faster to use `File`, so this solution has some performance advantages. I also had to write my own `ls` because I didn't want to rely on the one provided by the system as there are no guarantees on the output it provides.

I also suggest reading [How-To SU](https://su.chainfire.eu/), it has a lot of useful details on how to call the commands correctly.

Comment: Yeah I thought about using both methods. I just don't know the best way to implement this. How did you implement this?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab In my case it was a `FileItem` class which contained the methods similar to `File`'s. Internally it has two fields, `File` and `NativeFile`. When `NativeFile` is present, some calls are delegated to it. `NativeFile` is responsible for calling all the necessary commands.

Comment: So `FileItem` was your custom class that executes different pieces of code for rooted and unrooted phones? So for rooted devices `ls` with `su` and for unrooted devices `ls` with `sh`?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab No, for unrooted devices I have `File` inside `FileItem` because it does things more efficiently than `sh` and `ls`.

Comment: *it does things more efficiently*, could you explain, please?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab You get the result faster when you call the methods of `File` instead of running shell commands. I think it's pretty obvious because running a shell command will involve launching a separate process and parsing its results whereas `File` can call the system methods directly without all the overhead. The discussion got a little long, let us [continue in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105483/discussion-between-malcolm-and-superthomaslab).

Comment: You should looking at this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls before using `ls`

Comment: @Guillaume That is why I wrote my own `ls` which I have full control over as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Majora320 Didn't knew that command, but from Google I see that it can come quite useful. Not only for listing files, but also searching for files.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab And it's even more useful with the `-exec` argument - you can do things like `find ~ -name "*.mp3" -exec cp {} ~/Music \;`, which makes a lot of things easier and faster.

Comment: *Malcolm*, thanks for your help. I have an idea how I'm going to implement this. However, from that link that @Guillaume shared, I read that it is a bad practise to parse `ls`, because of newlines and special characters. So I'm still stuck at that point. Do you happen to know a way I can list all files in a directory with the "real" names? I just want an array of all the files in a directory, with the original names, so I can edit those files later.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Like I mentioned in the answer, I ended up writing my own command which does exactly what I want it to. That's probably the only alternative if you don't want to use the built-in command.

Comment: @Malcolm Hey, I think I got it working now. I use this terminal command: `stat -c '\\%n\%s\%F\%A\%Y\' <directory>*`. I will just split it at the back slashes. Do you have any suggestions? If I am right it support newlines.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab "Correct" is a rather fluid concept right now since we are way past what Google considers normal use of Android. I think it should work, but I would test with different symbols (unprintable, outside of BMP, etc.) and also check if it works on old versions of Android. If it still works, then you are probably fine.